# AVAudioRecorder Play the Recorded Item While Recording

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avaudiorecorder, audiokit

Is there a way I can play the file that is BEING RECORDED during the recording? That is, when the user plugs in an earphone with mic, he is able to hear his own voice through the earphone as he speaks into the mic, which means there is no looping to be worried about.

P.S. If `AVAudioRecorder` cannot achieve this, is there any way of doing this with `AudioKit`? If so, please tell me how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is you would have to use an [`AVCaptureSession`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture) to do this.

You can grab input from `AVCaptureDeviceInput`.

And then you can use [`AVCaptureOutputAudioDataOutput`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcaptureaudiodataoutput), which provides access to audio sample buffers as they are recorded.

```
extension RecordingViewController: AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {
    func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput,
                       didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer,
                       from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        output.connection(with: AVMediaType(rawValue: AVAudioSessionPortBuiltInSpeaker))
    }
}
```

**Edit:** It might be simpler and cleaner to implement this with AudioKit, however. Code would be something like this:

```
let microphone = AKMicrophone()
let mixer = AKMixer(microphone)
let booster = AKBooster(mixer, gain: 0)
AudioKit.output = booster

microphone.start()
do {
    try AudioKit.start()
} catch {
    print("AudioKit boot failed.")
}
```

Comment: I think the AudioKit version is what I'm looking for. Thanks!